Attempting to figure out an RTP stream to be able to listen to the payload
I am working on rebuilding a server for a voice chat program that was built around 2002.
This chat consists of chat rooms where you, as the client, could send voice to a server and that would be played out to all other clients connected to the same room.
I have managed to get a lot done but I am struggling with the voice side of things. I can successfully connect to my voice server and receive the transmitted audio from the client. This comes through as an RTP stream. I have successfully broken down this stream and I can listen to the payload, however, I don't know what format I am supposed to send this back to the connected clients. I have a Wireshark PCAP file of data that was captured back in the 2002 but I am unable to successfully play the payload with Wireshark, it's just white noise.
So in summary, I understand and can listen to the stream going out, I can't fully understand or play the stream coming back.
Below is an example of the outgoing and incoming stream. These are 2 different streams taken at completely different times by different people speaking in the chat room.
ideally what I need is to understand what the server needs to do to the incoming stream to send it back to the connected clients, but first I want to understand the stream and play the payload in  order to know what I need to do next.
# Outgoing stream
The SSRC (000f4242) is actually the ID of the speaker, the payload is terminated by this same ID in a different Byte Order. the payload type here is 3 (GSM) and I have successfully played the audio using the GSM codec.

**Length of Packet:**
00000094

**RTP Header:**
8003369bee2e9949000f4242

**Payload:**  d35f8919a3d2a0c8a3ad4a8cbc80c8a5cdd8e6d6e0b7a469b4617cc0a873914b23d29d7a595b84e0a9636fa6ded8a0af5c6a531a92a0929c6adaf5d08099b5966514d4608a5953c0c0b9528f289aeca01fe9792028bc8099253558e468c0c71a214936d3dd829952aea0ed7490b70c7ca0d5294664b25b2124a175d5237ae1589c7dd6f442420f00

# Incoming Stream
Here is the incoming stream, remember, this is a different time and source. This payload type is 0 and I am unable to listed to the payload, I also notice a repeating 34002 which I don't know what that would be.

**Length of Packet:**
000000ea

**RTP Header:**
8000913b02d62700038918b9

**Payload:**  
34002e89d4293cd787c90b026096aa5ec3b5aa7f1ae304e6a7d8e1fb25f0d073f55bfba01e1826fab830128f60c1703080ed000ad79634002e898febfc3ebf0e02702950ec72f3c7e06efc527d537e9717e6483ccea7074c13913ded632ab8d04777d059ec2009cf00504ce634002c8f1da4f9f5d3795f97d9bf236343a69c8c2e81799c6edcedf334282697d1e36a1d3e3a214a5000688781155dd0715c8064f7063400299d006dbb6b1f5614f2cfa61d8e4d06b83ec7e79a0728b14c95fc9d112345658eeff3bff8ea97d0b18e204dac50b5ac8069f2160000b9188903


What voice chat application was this?  Was it a push-to-talk sort of thing?  I remember Mplayer around then worked this way.  If you can dig up a copy of it, the application binary might have some answers for you, even just in its DLLs.  There were some other applications that had bespoke codecs.  Also, can you clarify which direction you have working?  It isn't entirely clear from the question.

Hi Brad,
It was a push-to-talk chat application called Paltalk. It's actually still around today but I am rebuilding the server  to make the 2002 version work.
I currently have the outgoing stream working, which is coming from the Paltalk client. It's the incoming stream (to the client) that I am having trouble with, it doesn't seem to be in quite the same format.
Here is a link to the Github repo
https://github.com/NetStorm84/PaltalkServer

PalTalk!!!!!!  Man, I loved PalTalk.  PalTalk was the best because it was the only instant messaging client that fit on a single floppy disk... which in my area was required because our phone lines were old and downloading anything over dial-up was tedious.  We'd share the floppy around, and that was faster.  I actually started working on a text-only client for a BBS for PalTalk at one point, for all the terminal users I knew.  Also ended up working on some embedded browser, working with Perry.  Did not know PalTalk was still around!  Very cool.

Alright, looking in my archives, I still have Paltalk 3.1 (well, the EXE says 3.0.25) from March 2, 2001.  According to the readme, voice conferencing and video was added around this time.  Let me know if these files would be helpful.

Also, if this is helpful... found some old resources for popup windows via Archive.org, looks like mostly (all?) ads:  https://web.archive.org/web//http://216.74.151.150:8080/

I uploaded my files here:  https://archive.org/details/paltalk-3.1

Thanks Brad, I actually have the client. I just need to understand the above RTP packet to get the voice chat side of things working. Here is what I have working so far.... https://youtu.be/B9VWBmMS0Lk?si=CJhcWaq8LkXFE-gS
